# Getting "Could not initialize class sun.security.ec.SunEC" How to Proceed?

Tags: java, initialization

After coming back to a part of my code base that hadn't been touched for a few weeks, I got the rather terse message:  "Could not initialize class sun.security.ec.SunEC"  from my functional REST test cases.

I'm not making much progress figuring out how tackle this one, there's no other error information (no stack trace) and not much on the Internet.  I expect an update has changed something since everything was working.

Does anyone have any suggestions or insight for fixing this one?

Ubuntu 16.10
Java 8, Oracle, "1.8.0_131"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a missing library libsunec.so.  I was using the alpine docker container V3.4 which contained the library, but when I upgraded to V3.5, a "glich" in my build process actually had me still using V3.4.  When that was indirectly "fixed," and I unknowingly started using V3.5, the error was suddenly, and confusingly, uncovered because libsunec.so was left out of alpine V3.5.  See: https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/6809